# SQL Server - breakdown amounts into fixed prices

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-cursor

Lets say we have a table containing different payments (session_payments) for a session that has different activities (activity_prices). Mind you, there may be a lot more than 2 payments for each session.

| session_id | payment_method | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 3 | 50 |
| 1000 | 6 | 200 |

| session_id | activity | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 | 100 |
| 1000 | 2 | 150 |

I need to create  payment records for each activity

In this case

| session_id | activity | payment_method | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 | 3 | 50 |
| 1000 | 1 | 6 | 50 |
| 1000 | 2 | 6 | 150 |

I tried a cursor approach but it works well only when the payment is larger than the activity price.
I think it needs some sort of recursive action which cursor cannot provide.

Here is the simplified SQL environment

```
CREATE TABLE session_payments
(session_id     varchar(128)    null,
 payment_method int             null,
 amount         numeric(10,2)   null)
 go
 CREATE TABLE activity_prices
(session_id     varchar(128)    null,
 activity       numeric(10,0)   null,
 price          numeric(10,2)   null)
 go
 
 INSERT session_payments
 SELECT '1000',3,50 
 INSERT session_payments
 SELECT '1000',6,200
 
 INSERT activity_prices
 SELECT '1000',1,100
 INSERT activity_prices
 SELECT '1000',2,150    
 go
```

Comment: Will the totals (per session in each table) always match?

Comment: Hi Salman. Yes. The activity prices always match with the payments